# Primefaces selectOneMenu listener not called with Objects other than Strings

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7

I'm implementing a webapp using Jsf 2.0 and Primefaces 3.2.
I've noticed this unexpected behavoiur: I have a `selectOneMenu` and a `commandButton`, as below

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selsel" value="#{bean.myObj}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.myObjList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton id="btnid" value="Ok" actionListener="#{bean.updateSelectValues()}" />
```

What happens is that if `myObj` is not a `String`, the `updateSelectValues` method is not called. I can't see any exception or error at all, it's just not called. Here's the backing bean:

```
private List<MyObj> myObjList;
private MyObj myObj;
// getters and setters

public void updateSelectValues() {
  System.out.println(this.myObj);
}
```

The code for myObj:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String param1;
  private int param2;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("MyObj [param1=");
    builder.append(this.param1);
    builder.append(", param2=");
    builder.append(this.param2);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because HTML and HTTP does not understand Java objects. All Java objects are converted to `String` when HTML is to be produced by JSF. All HTTP request parameters which are `String` are supposed to be converted back to Java object when the submitted form data is to be processed by JSF.

As to your concrete problem, if you have added a `<h:message>`, `<h:messages>` or the PrimeFaces equivalent to the form (and also updated it on ajax submits), then you should have noticed a conversion error for "null converter". Also, if you have paid attention to the server log, you should also have seen a warning about an unhandled message.

You need to create a custom [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) which converts between `MyObj` and its unique `String` representation. For example:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=MyObj.class)
public class MyObjConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object valueToRender) {
        // Convert MyObj to its unique String representation.
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        // Convert String to MyObj.
    }

}
```

Usually those objects are already stored in some database or mapping by their ID. You then use exactly that ID as unique `String` representation.