# Primefaces: Conversion Error setting value 'Admin' for 'null Converter'

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am getting error in this code, i am stuck at this point. Please help me.

getter and setter for selectedRole, allRolesList are included in code

**java code**

```
private String selectedRole;


List<String> allRolesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(!roleList.isEmpty()){
        isRolesPresent = true;
        for(UserRole ur : roleList){
            allRolesList.add(ur.getRoleName().toString());

/* printing allRolesList results: [admin] */

System.out.print("allRolesList "+allRolesList);

        }
    }else{
        isRolesPresent = false;
    }
```

**prime-faces code:**

```
        <p:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{usersDAO.selectedUser}" effect="fade" required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="Role cannot be null">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{usersDAO.allRolesList}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{usersDAO.selectedUser}` is apparently not of type `String`. JSF doesn't know how to convert `String` to `User` as there is no converter been registered for `User` type, hence the error message which you got.

You'd normally need to create a custom `Converter` for this, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601710/primefaces-selectonemenu-listener-not-called-with-objects-other-than-strings/10601865#10601865), but based on the given Java code, you *actually* need `#{usersDAO.selectedRole}` instead which is already of `String` type. So you don't need to create a custom `Converter`.

```html
<p:selectOneMenu ... value="#{usersDAO.selectedRole}">
```

---

By the way, a managed bean with "DAO" in the name is quite strange. Are you sure that you aren't mixing concepts or tight-coupling different responsibilities in a single class (which would lead to poor reusability/maintainability)?

Comment: A DAO class is normally not a JSF managed bean. It's normally a property of a JSF managed bean. A DAO class is normally a class which contains all the database interaction code such as `find()`, `list()`, `create()`, `save()`, `delete()`, etc. This is absolutely not to be used as a JSF managed bean.