# javax.faces.model.SelectItem is storing value object as String

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primefaces selectOneMenu listener not called with Objects other than Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601710/primefaces-selectonemenu-listener-not-called-with-objects-other-than-strings)

I am creating `List` of `SelectItem` as:

```
List<SelectItem> activityGlobalTypes = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

for (ActivityTypeXMLModel activityTypeXMLModel : filteredActivityTypeXMLModels) {
    activityGlobalTypes.add(new SelectItem(activityTypeXMLModel, activityTypeXMLModel.getParent()));
}
```

This is the dropdown menu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="activityGlobalMenu" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.activityParentName}" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.activityGlobalTypes}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{adminController.updateDependentActivity}" />                        
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now from the method `updateDependentActivity`

```
public void updateDependentActivity(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    SelectOneMenu menu = (SelectOneMenu) event.getComponent();
    System.out.println(menu.getValue());//it prints com.edfx.adb.xml.model.ActivityTypeXMLModel@7b6fe3c4

    if(menu.getValue() instanceof ActivityTypeXMLModel) {
        System.out.println("value is ActivityTypeXMLModel"); // I was expecting this one
    } else if(menu.getValue() instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("value is String"); //this line is executing 
    } else {
        System.out.println("unknown");
    }   
}
```

I have checked the source code of `SelectItem` and it is storing value in object form. Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: To the point, you need a converter or an alternate approach. See also `[selectonemenu]` tag wiki page for some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: Or, if you happen to use the JSF utility library OmniFaces already, then all you need to do is to add `converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"` attribute to the component.

Comment: @BalusC I have used `omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter` after your suggestion and also I have changed the datatype of `adminController.activityDTO.activityParentName` to String to `ActivityTypeXMLModel`, then it works. Also extending `org.omnifaces.converter.SelectItemsConverter` it works. Is there any way to let the datatype of `adminController.activityDTO.activityParentName` as `String` and achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the point, your problem is caused because non-standard Java objects (i.e. no `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` for which JSF has builtin converters) are by default converted to `String` by a simple `Object#toString()` call. So complex objects end up as their `toString()` representation in the generated HTML `<option value>`. Exactly this value get submitted back to the server.

You can solve this in different ways:

1. Provide a custom [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) which converts between `ActivityTypeXMLModel` and `String`. This is answered in among others the following question: [Primefaces selectOneMenu listener not called with Objects other than Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601710/primefaces-selectonemenu-listener-not-called-with-objects-other-than-strings)
2. If you're using the [JSF utility library OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can also use the provided converters [`omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) or [`omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter) to perform the generic conversion based on the `<f:selectItem(s)>` value without the need to write a custom converter.
3. Do not supply a complex Java object type as item value, but instead supply a standard Java object type, such as `String`. In your case, you seem to want to use the `activityParentName` property of the `ActivityTypeXMLModel` object. For easy traversion using the since JSF2 introduced `var` attribute of `<f:selectItems>`, you only need to change the value to be a `List<ActivityTypeXMLModel>` instead of `List<SelectItem>`.

   ```
   private List<ActivityTypeXMLModel> activityGlobalTypes;
   ```

   with

   ```html
   <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.activityGlobalTypes}" var="type"
       itemValue="#{type.activityParentName}" itemLabel="#{type.parent}" />
   ```

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Answer (score 0):

Is `adminController.activityDTO.activityParentName` a `selectItem` or a String? Perhaps, it should be a selectItem in this case.

Comment: No, it definitely shouldn't be.

Comment: `adminController.activityDTO.activityParentName` is String.